# Angular element JQuery .on command not working properly

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, typescript

I have a directive written in typescript using angular JS, 1.5.3, and I'm using webpack to load angular and jquery etc. I've managed to get Angular to use the full JQuery instead of jquerylite.

However, in the following snippet, my element.on doesn't trigger on the event. However when I just use jquery separately to do the same thing it works.

i.e. console only prints "hit me instead"

```
function DropdownCloseHandler(): ng.IDirective {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: (scope, element, attrs) => {
      element.on('hidden.bs.dropdown', (e) => {
        console.log('hit me');
      });
      $('#search-box-dropdown').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', (e) => {
        console.log('hit me instead');
      });
    }
  };
}

angular
  .module('components')
  .directive('dropdownClose', DropdownCloseHandler);
```

both `element` and the `$('#search-box-dropdown')` seem to refer to the same element in my chrome debugger.

[image: chrome debugger info]

Does anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, when using `.on`, you will have to bind it to the `document`.

So, I would use:

```
$(document).on('hidden.bs.dropdown', (e) => {
  console.log('hit me');
});
```

I've never used it with angular though and I see no action to make it work.  But try that first?

Comment: isn't that the same as just using a jquery selector?  $('#search-box-dropdown').on works as well, but it defeats the whole purpose of having a directive attached to an element, with the element itself passed to the directive.